# chromium-ozone-wayland cannot init wayland platform and connect to wayland display

Tags: chromium, yocto, wayland

I built chromium-ozone-wayland successfully but im getting error on runtime.

Error Output :

ERROR : XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment
ERROR:wayland_connection.cc(218) Failed to connect to wayland display: no such file or directory(2)
ERROR:ozone_platform_wayland.cc(220) Failed to initialize wayland platform
ERROR:env.cc(255) The platform failed to initialize. exiting.

I used this repo : https://github.com/OSSystems/meta-browser/tree/master/meta-chromium

What could it be caused by?

Comment: Do you run the app as another user, root?

Comment: @273K

i have one test user and root. i declared like that :

EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS += " \
 usermod -p '\$6\$mkrootpasswd\$SlYuF6KkjjL2qENSmGZ/.cHpkR6h7EepJdMyFLb6tmpz5FlIg6DMxooYAWQ5k8xG7I4fgHR1DY0htsMnrlD.H.' root; \
 useradd -p '' testuser; \
"

I logged into both users and tried, but got the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
./chrome --in-process-gpu
```

see this  https://github.com/OSSystems/meta-browser/issues/599